# Did lightning:accordion get the update from the roadmap in summer 18'? (multipleexpanded sections)

Tags: lightning, summer-18

[image]

I understand the roadmap is not always a set in stone delivery map but I would assume SF would update this document to reflect those things that they miss / achieve for transparency reasons? Maybe not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neither the documentation nor the Summer '18 release notes mention multiple expanded sections. Also, road maps are usually published periodically, but you should never consider these to be "live" documents. They will not be updated retroactively.